# Get the title of the active window

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi, dllimport, user32

I have declared the following WinAPI calls

```
<DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetActiveWindow", SetLastError:=True,
    CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True,
    CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Shared Function GetActiveWindowHandle() As System.IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetWindowText", SetLastError:=True,
    CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True,
    CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Shared Function GetActiveWindowText(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, _
                                            ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
                                            ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

Then, I call this subroutine to get the text in the active window's title bar

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim caption As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetActiveWindowHandle()
    GetActiveWindowText(hWnd, caption, caption.Capacity)
    MsgBox(caption.ToString)
End Sub
```

Finally, I get the following error

> Unable to find an entry point named 'GetWindowText' in DLL
>   'USER32.DLL'

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to change CharSet:=CharSet.Auto

Comment: [this](http://vbtab.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-get-title-of-currently-active-window-in-vb-net.html) worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<DllImport("USER32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetWindowText", SetLastError:=True,
    CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True,
```

You insisted on ExactSpelling.  Which is the problem, there are *two* versions of GetWindowText exported by user32.dll.  GetWindowTextA and GetWindowTextW.  The A version uses an ansi string, a legacy string format with 8-bit characters encoded in the default code page that was last used in Windows ME.  The W version uses a Unicode string, encoded in utf-16, the native Windows string type.  The pinvoke marshaller will try either of them, based on the CharSet but you stopped it from doing so by using ExactSpelling := True.  So it cannot find GetWindowText, it doesn't exist.

Either use EntryPoint := "GetWindowTextW" or drop ExactSpelling.